# Java Prepared statements for PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to create simple application for 2 databases - Oracle and PostgreSQL. Is there any way to use one Java code for all databases? I tried this:

```
public String init()
{
    String user_name = null;
    try
    {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        if (ctx == null)
            throw new Exception("Boom - No Context");

        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/DefaultDB");

        if (ds != null)
        {
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

            if (conn != null)
            {
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("select id, user_name from user where username = " + user);
                if (rst.next())
                {
                    user_name = rst.getString("user_name");
                }
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return user_name;
}
```

How I can use prepared statements with this code?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? You should be able to just use SQL of `select id, user_name from user where username = ?` and then prepare the statement appropriately, set the parameters and execute. It's not clear whether your difficulty is in using prepared statements *at all*, or in using them portably. Please could you clarify? (And do you really have columns `user_name` and `username` in your database?)

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html for the basics of using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but the usual approach to multi-database compatibility is twofold:

1. Place all your SQL statements in resource files and load the appropriate resource at runtime
2. Where the statement or logic structures differ (requiring different parameters, etc), write the logic for both databases and choose the correct path depending on the database you are using.

Some database abstraction layers (Hibernate, Spring JDBC) can help with a lot of the work, but you will still need to be very aware of the differences and code for them.

Answer (score -1):

> You can work with more than one-database by single java-Code, but
>   following way,
>
> 1. Per Database separate Connection needs to be set-up

and you can use `PreparedStatement`  into your `code` likewise,

```
String selectSQL = "select id, user_name from user where username = ?"
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);

preparedStatement.setString(1, "userName");

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

Comment: Can't use query methods that take a query string on a PreparedStatement.