# Select data from PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I created this simple table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "User"(
 "id" Integer NOT NULL,
 "user_name" Text,
 "first_name" Text,
 "last_name" Text,
 "last_login" Date,
 "date_registered" Date,
 "role" Integer,
 "can_login" Integer
)
;

-- Add keys for table User

ALTER TABLE "User" ADD CONSTRAINT "Key1" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
;
```

And I tried to make simple query code from Tomcat servlet

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/DefaultDB")
    private DataSource ds;

    public void databaseQuery() throws SQLException
    {
        if (ds == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        if (conn == null)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USER");

//            ps.setString(1, user);
            // Get data from Oracle Database
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            while (result.next())
            {
                System.out.println(">>>>> value " + result);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ps != null)
            {
                ps.close();
            }
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

But after I inserted some test data nothing happens. What is the proper way to get data from PostgreSQL using Java code?

Comment: please, refer this might be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258247/java-prepared-statements-for-postgresql/36258500#36258500

Comment: you need to retrieve values by column name like `result.getInt("id");`

Comment: You can't display a `ResultSet` like that. You need to iterate over it using `ResultSet.next()`. Please see the JDBC tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should **really** avoid [quoted identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). They are *much* more trouble in the long run that they are worth it.